When moving countries, what should you list as location in job application?
I will be moving in with my partner in country B, from country A, after finishing my degree, so am currently looking for work there (I have citizenship of both country A and B).
I have noticed that I am getting rejected quickly by most applications, even if I am well qualified, so am a little suspicious it may be due to listing my country as "country A" (I have detailed my relocation in my cover letter and citizenships in my CV).
Would it be OK to list my partner's address on my application or would that be unethical/fraudulent etc as I am not yet a permanent resident of country B? I have to input my exact address or location on online application forms.

When you say Permanent Resident - do you mean the Legal term or just the fact you are not currently living there? As this drastically changes the answer.

@TheDemonLord The OP said he has citizenship of both countries.  So "permanent resident" must mean "not living there"

Some more context might be useful here - how/where are you 'listing' location? Is it just on your CV/cover letter (so that @PlayerOne's answer is open to you) or is the issue with e.g. an online application system that requires you to enter an address/country of residence?

@TheDemonLord yes sorry, it is just that I am not currently living there. I also don't have a proper identity number as you need to have been registered as living there for one

@OCSE - See, that last part is potentially an issue - and is why I asked - If you are going to put you live in Country A, but you dont have an ID number, then you risk that being a red flag with an employer and then they will think you have lied.

Alternatively to the other answers, I think your approach, with listing your partners address, where you will be living when working for the applied jobs, is also a valid approach.
My wife did that as well, when applying cross country (800km) for jobs, at the end of her studies, before moving.
When asked in the interview, she explained the situation and everything was fine.

I think it's fine, but some care and honesty is appropriate. If you decide you can't move after all, or if you come to the company afterwards to help with visa or moving costs, or if you delay your start by a lot because you haven't moved yet, the company may feel a little "baited-and-switched".

@xLeitix Obviously you should not just lie and I don't consider this a lie, especially if you already have a place there. Also obviously don't hide any additional hurdles from the company. But from the question I felt like, the moving is a non issue here and also since it is the partner, the probability of going there eventually is pretty high.
As I wrote, I would also mention the circumstances in the first communication/interview, but this was also already done by OP before via "cover letter".

@xLeitix The problem with "delaying the start" or "not being able to work there at all" are things that can also happen if you live close. So for me there is no special attention needed. Things change, it's just important to then act accordingly.

Thank you, I think I'll just do this. I had started to omit my location from the CV but it gets quite difficult when they directly ask you on the online application. I am just a bit worried that they will see my foreign email address and mobile number and assume I have entered a false address.

@OCSE You could easily get a 'non-geographic' email address (e.g. gmail.com, outlook.com), and perhaps even pick up a local SIM card.

It sounds like the issue is getting filtered out by HR (or worse, HR software) before getting a chance to explain in an interview.

@T.E.D. yes maybe(/probably), because he put an address from another country. That's why my suggestion is to put the address from the country where the company is :) This should prevent getting filtered out.

Take the address off completely, and just list your email address (and phone number if you have one in the country you're applying for jobs in).
Be aware that companies might expect you to be available for an on-site interview. You can ask to have one via a video conferencing tool, which they may or may not accommodate.
Note that this advice would be different if you were not a citizen of the country you are applying to.

The edit makes it sound like this might be a required entry on an online form?

@T.E.D. Yep, for an online entry form this would only be useful if the address field isn't mandatory. That information wasn't in the post at the time I wrote this answer, and I still feel it's useful for other methods of applying to jobs in different countries (or even cities). I've used it myself successfully.

Player One has a fantastic response, and I'd like to piggyback on that.  Yes, omit your address.  If you have citizenship in country B, and you are soliciting work in  country B, put "B Citizen" in smaller text just beneath your name.  Do NOT put "A Citizen/B Citizen" -- this is oversharing.
This approach will yield more responses.  However, you need to be prepared to accept in-person interviews in B.  Some companies will want to do multiple interviews, so that's another consideration.  When you can speak with a decision maker or influencer, you will have to do the best to demonstrate your unique selling proposition (i.e. why they should hire you) and then also be transparent about the fact that you live in country A and also have citizenship in B.  Show a willingness to give verification on your citizenship early in the process, because no one wants to go through rounds and rounds of interviews to later learn that they can't hire you without a lot of extra work on their part.

This seems like weird advice to me. Do you personally list your citizenship this prominently on job applications? I certainly never have

@David_h Yes, I do.  When I'm actively searching (I do contract work), I dislike being bombarded with questions that one could just read off the top of my resume.  So at the top are my name, email address, "US CITIZEN", phone number, city, state, and zip code.
I've literally had recruiters call me and I could tell that they were reading from a script, and clueless about the work that I do.  I feel a tad bit sorry for them (most don't last 90 days!) but I am particular about them wasting my time.

In many industries (in the US at least, don't know about elsewhere) you will be asked whether you are a US citizen at some point in every single interview process, so you may as well save a question by listing it preemptively.

Yes, of course. Most importantly, not a... single HR will believe that "I am in the process of moving in B". You will be a migrant for them. They will see it that you want them to not only employ you, but also help you to migrate. While you do not even know anything about their country.
Bosses have a tricky mindset, it might be the long-term result of keeping the very, very, very diverse problems what a company meets. Part of this mindset is not intuitively comprehensible for an ordinary mortal.
One of these is, to have a real chance to called on an interview, you must be on the same city. The same country is an absolute must, but the same city is what is really expected.
My own mental model about them, that the reality for them, in this matters, ends at the border of their city. I.e. other people, even customers with them they are video-meeting, are only faces on the screen.
Another problem is that you can not lie. So you need to create a believable intermediary state, which is already not a lie. If you have an apartman in their city, with an official address, that is most likely enough. Note, their "reality border" applies also for that they will want to employ guys who are already working in the same city, but you need to live with it.
